# Having Trouble with Checkbox Staying Checked via LocalStorage after Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I currently have a script that clicks on a random checkbox upon page load and page refresh, and I'm able to see the value of the input that I assigned for the randomly selected checkbox through localStorage.

However, I haven't been able keep any of the checkboxes checked upon a page load or a page refresh using localStorage and I'm a bit stumped at the moment.

html

```
<div id="all-games">
   <div>
      <h2>Microsoft Xbox</h2>
         <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/call of duty 3.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="cod-3" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Call of Duty 3</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="phantasy-star-online" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode I</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="phantasy-star-online-ii" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/shrek.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="shrek" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Shrek</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/soulcaliber ii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="soulcaliber-ii" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>SoulCalibur II</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/spiderman 2.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="spiderman-2" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Spider-Man 2</li>
            <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/star wars episode iii.png">
            <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" value="star-wars-episode-iii" onchange="scrollToGame()"/></label>Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
   const games = document.querySelectorAll(".video-game input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)"); // select games that are currently not checked
   const checkbox = Math.floor(Math.random() * games.length); // get a random index from 0 to games length
   const scrolledGame = games[checkbox];
   scrolledGame.click(); // click on the checkbox for the randomly selected game
   const gameValue = scrolledGame.value;

   function scrollToGame() { 
      scrolledGame.scrollIntoView({ 
         behavior: "smooth"
      });

   };

   if (scrolledGame.checked) {
      localStorage.setItem('game title', gameValue); // title value of the selected checkbox via localStorage
      scrolledGame.checked = true;
   };

   if (localStorage.getItem('game title') === gameValue) {
      scrolledGame.checked = true;
      console.log(scrolledGame.checked);
   };
</script>
```

Comment: perhaps you are *doing something wrong™* in your script

Comment: I meant to post the actual code, but realized I forgot to post them upon submission of my question.

Comment: so, on page load you select a random game, and write that to localStorage overwriting whatever was already there ... and then you get from local storage what you just wrote ... I think the issue is that your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

re: I haven't been able keep any of the checkboxes checked upon a page load or a page refresh using localStorage

That's because each time you refresh the page a new checkbox is checked.  There is nothing wrong with the way you are saving and retrieving the 'game title'. If you want the checkbox states to be persistent, then don't change them when you refresh the page. Instead, retrieve the 'game title' and check the corresponding checkbox.

The following code will maintain the persistance of the last checkbox that you check.

```
<body>
<div id="all-games">
    <div>
       <h2>Microsoft Xbox</h2>
          <ul id="games" class="no-bullets">
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/call of duty 3.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="cod-3" onchange="save('cod-3')"/></label>Call of Duty 3</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="phantasy-star-online" onchange="save('phantasy-star-online')"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode I</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/phantasy star online episode i & ii.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="phantasy-star-online-ii" onchange="save('phantasy-star-online-ii')"/></label>Phantasy Star Online Episode II</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/shrek.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="shrek" onchange="save('shrek')"/></label>Shrek</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/soulcaliber ii.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="soulcaliber-ii" onchange="save('soulcaliber-ii')"/></label>SoulCalibur II</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/spiderman 2.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="spiderman-2" onchange="save('spiderman-2')"/></label>Spider-Man 2</li>
             <img src="./Game Covers/Microsoft/Microsoft Xbox/star wars episode iii.png">
             <li class="video-game"><label><input type="checkbox" id="star-wars-episode-iii" onchange="save('star-wars-episode-iii')"/></label>Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
 </div>

 <script>

    if (localStorage.getItem('game title')) {  // used on each page refresh
      let game = localStorage.getItem('game title')
      document.querySelector(`input[id=${game}]`).checked = true;
    }

    function save(game) { // used when the checkboxes are checked and unchecked
      if (document.querySelector(`input[id=${game}]`).checked === true) {
        localStorage.setItem('game title', game); 
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('game title', '')
      }
    }
 </script> 

</body>
```